# How do I publish my apk as a package on GitHub

Tags: android, github, package, github-actions

I have created a kivy app and built an apk using GitHub Actions

https://github.com/sameermahajan/Paadas

How do I publish the generated apk so that it shows up under Packages tab of my GitHub profile? Under there I only see 6 registries (namely Docker, Maven, NuGet, RubyGems, npm, Containers) and as I understand an android apk, it does not belong to any of those...

Comment: Yes, that's not supported. You can upload it as an artifact as part of your release.

Comment: See https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release.